# Query to find students who took many courses together

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a query to find all students who took many courses together.

Tables schema:

- `Student`: ID int, Fname nvarchar(50), Lname nvarchar(50)
- `Course`: Course_ID int , Name nvarchar(100), Created_date datetime
- `Enrollment`: Student_ID int, Course_id int

For example: I want to see students who have taken more than three courses together.

I want result like this:

```
Course.name, Student.fname, student.lname
CSC 201,        Jhon ,         Khal
CSC 201,        Mike,          Alan
CSC 201,        Peter,         Wick
IS 220,         Jhon ,         Khal
IS 220,         Mike,          Alan
IS 220,         Peter,         Wick
.               Jhon ,         Khal
.               Mike,          Alan
.               Peter,         Wick
.
.
.
.
```

This is what I came up with:

```
select Course.name, Student.fname, student.lname  from enrollment e
join course c on c.course.Id = e.course.Id
join student s on s.id = e.student_ID
```

Comment: Homework, and you expect us to do it for you? At least make some effort and show us sample table data and its matching expected result, and your current query attempt.

Comment: The answer will most probably include a self join, group by and having.

Comment: "this is what I cam up with" - and then? did you try running it? what happened? why was that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> How to write a query to find all students who took many courses together.

I would use aggregation and `having`.  For three arbitrary courses:

```
select s.id, s.fname, s.lname 
from student s join
     enrollment e
     on s.id = e.student_ID 
group by s.id, s.fname, s.lname 
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Notice that the `courses` table is not needed.  `enrollment` has sufficient information.  This is *not* returning information about the courses -- because your question is only asking for the *students* who meet the criterion.

If you want to see the courses, then `string_agg()` is the simplest solution to put the values on one row:

```
select s.id, s.fname, s.lname,
       string_agg(c.name, ', ') as courses
from student s join
     enrollment e
     on s.id = e.student_ID join
     course c
     on c.course.Id = e.course.Id
group by s.id, s.fname, s.lname 
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Do note that `string_agg()` is a recent addition to SQL Server, so it may not be available in your version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT C.Name course_name, 
A.fname,
A.lname
FROM Student A
INNER JOIN Enrollment B ON A.ID = B.Student_ID
INNER JOIN Course C ON B.Course_id = C.Course_id
WHERE A.ID IN
( 
    SELECT Student_ID  
    FROM Enrollment
    GROUP BY Student_ID  
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3 
)
```